# Why is HTTP protocol stateless if it can deal with persistent connections?

Tags: http

The HTTP protocol is stateless, but I found this on the Kurose-Ross book:

```
The default HTTP method is with persistent connections and pipeling.
```

This means that it can handle multiple requests, so it keeps opened the socket of a client that wants to ask multiple requests.Is that true? If yes, why is HTTP protocol considered stateless?

Comment: "A stateless protocol is such that treats each request as an independent transaction, unrelated to previous requests" ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol)) How pipelines and persistent connections change this?

Comment: Because if multiple resources are requested, the TCP connection remains opened, and so the socket is still "alive" in the server.And so the state is saved.

Comment: State of HTTP? No. It's state of lower-level protocols. And HTTP server itself shouldn't care how two HTTP requests were sent.

Comment: That was my doubt, it's clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTTP persistent connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) relate to TCP connection being left open. HTTP operates on top of TCP - so TCP can be connected and/or stateful whereas HTTP would not. TCP is just the transport for HTTP.

If you look at the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), you can see that TCP is on layer 4 (transport), whereas HTTP is on layer 7 (application). HTTP is not tied to TCP and could use other ways of transport too - as a protocol, it is not "inheriting" features from TCP.

(Note also that the persistent connection is not really persistent for a very long time. For Apache 2, it is open only for 5 seconds per default, and "According to RFC 2616 (page 46), a single-user client should not maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy".)

Comment: So HTTP is stateless because at the application layer no state in saved, where at transport layer (TCP layer) the state is saved.Is that statement true?

Comment: With HTTP presistent connections, yes, that is true. In general TCP does not always save the state and HTTP has "hacks" that involve state, but that is beside the point of this question.